# How to run a code analysis locally from the command line using a quality profile on the SonarQube server?

Tags: command-line, gulp, sonarqube, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis

On my SonarQube server I have 2 quality profiles (`1 for C# and 1 for JS`).

How to run a code analysis from the command line locally using them (**retain them on server, without using tools like SonaLint**) or using a gulp task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at the documentation of sonarqube for analyzing source code ( current link https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/overview/) - there you find a lot of useful scanners for different environments and languages.

You just need to configure them properly, but this is also something you can find within the docs of sonarqube.

Comment: Dead link.  Which is why link-only answers are worse than useless.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command line scanner. It will run an analysis locally from your command line.

Make sure, that you set `sonar.host.url` in `sonar-project.properties`, so that the correct quality profiles will be taken into account.